# Actions while logging in java with log4j and slf4j

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j, slf4j

I am using log4j wrapped with slf4j in my springboot application. Every time I call log.warn() or log.error(), I want to call a function (to increment a count).

What's the simplest and cleanest way to do it?

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve with that counter? Looks like you are trying to reinvent metrics and now how many warnings/errors there have been.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'm reinvending metrics, but I'd like to push the numbers to a centralized service, and view it graphically.

Comment: Yeah that is reinventing metrics. Spring Boot already supports that out-of-the-box. I remember a metrics extension for slf4j which counted the certain log levels being recorded. I suspect it is a matter of just adding that dependency (if it isn't included already).

Comment: Are you talking about dropwizard?

Comment: That is where those metrics originated but is now a library in its own, embraced by both Spring and Spring Boot. So I would even expect those metrics for logging to be available out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible in log4j or slf4j but you could use a Filter in logback: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html